# Completing the square in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am having trouble understanding how to complete the square in matrix form. I can't find any source online for a clear, final equation for that.
However, I would also like to grasp the intuition behind it. 
Thanks.

To give an example:

$$ x'Mx-2b'x=(x−M^{−1}b)′M(x−M^{−1}b)−b′M^{−1}b $$

How do I get that solution?

Comment: It’s very similar to completing the square for numbers excep that matrices do not necessarily commute $$(A+B)^2=A^2+AB+BA+B^2$$

Comment: yes but I often found equation in the forms of $$ x'Ax+x'b $$ which I am supposed to solve by completing the square, and I have no idea how to approach that

Comment: fair enough, I'll pick another example:
$$ x'Mx-2b'x $$ 
I know the solution of this one: $$ (x-M^{-1}b)'M(x-M^{-1}b)-b'M^{-1}b $$ 

But I don't know how to derive it

Comment: Prime is transpose I guess ??

Comment: yes, and M is symmetric and invertible

Comment: There’s a $x’b$ missing in the case you know

Comment: $$(x-M^{-1}b)’M(x-M^{-1}b)=x’b+b’x+b’M^{-1}b$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, it is implicit that $M$ is symmetric (because you have $M'^{-1}M=I$). Hence $M=SS'$ for some $S$. Let $u=x-M^{-1}b$ and you get the expression
\begin{align}
uSS'u'-b(S')^{-1}Sb'.
\end{align}
Let's say you set it equal to a certain complex number $z$. Then
\begin{align}
uSS'u'=b(S')^{-1}Sb'+z.
\end{align} Note that $S$ is invertible and both sides are complex numbers. The left hand side is the norm-squared of a complex vector. You can choose any vector $v$ with norm-squared equal to the right hand side and let $u=S^{-1}v=x-M^{-1}b$. Hence $x=S^{-1}v+M^{-1}b$.

Answer (score 3):

If it helps, the general form of matrix algebra is analogous to algebra with scalar variables except multiplication of matrices don't commute, so we write quadratic terms as a vector transpose times its transpose, $x^T x$, instead of with a square like $x^2$, and matrix inverses are always as  $M^{-1}$ instead of say $1/M$.

So the matrix algebra expression $x^T M x - 2 b^T x $ is like the real-valued polynomial $M x^2 - 2bx$.

How can we complete the square for $M x^2 - 2bx$? Well we can rewrite by factoring out the quadratic coefficient as $M(x^2 - 2 (b/M) x)$ and we see how to complete the square as
$$M (x^2 - 2 (b/M) x + (b/M)^2 - (b/M)^2)   = M((x - b/M)^2 - (b/M)^2) = (x - b/M)^2 M - b^2/M$$ Actually this is almost exactly our matrix expression $(x - b M^{-1})^T M (x - bM^{-1}) - b^T M^{-1} b  $ except written out in matrix form so all the dimensions and non-commutativity works out. You can now do the same complete the square steps in matrix form and see the equations look very similar.

Comment: Can you explain how you would "do the steps in matrix form"? I can't understand how to "factor a matrix out" ($M$ in this case) for example.

Comment: There is a rigorous explanation for this  but what I'm doing is pretending the matrices are scalars and using the result to guess what the answer should look like

Comment: If it's at all possible/quick for you to give those rigorous algebraic manipulations, I would greatly appreciate it. No worries if not though -- thanks for the very useful answer anyway!

Comment: Well I always struggled with linear algebra matrix manipulations, matrix calculus in particular, because I never learned them properly. What I had in mind is a bunch of identities from the Matrix Cookbook but I guess simplifying these expressions comes with experience. Maybe you can ask a new question that's more detailed on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I used a trick from here: https://learnbayes.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=77:completesquare&catid=83&Itemid=479&showall=1&limitstart=

$$ x'Mx-2bx = x'Mx-b'x-b'x $$ 
we can add $MM^{-1}$ in the middle terms:
$$ x'Mx-b'M^{-1}Mx-b'M^{-1}Mx $$

now let $$ M^{-1}b=u $$

so rewrite

$$ x'Mx-u'Mx-u'Mx = $$

which becomes a simple square. Notice that we need to substract the third term

$$ (x-u)M(x-u)-u'Mu = (x-M^{-1}b)M(x-M^{-1}b)-(M^{-1}b)'MM^{-1}b = $$

finally simplify the last bit
$$ (x-M^{-1}b)M(x-M^{-1}b)-b'M^{-1}MM^{-1}b  = (x-M^{-1}b)M (x-M^{-1}b)-b'M^{-1}b  $$

So what I learnt from this is that the trick is to try to get the expression in the form of $ x'Mx-2b'Mx $