# Write a matrix function in the completed square form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$x$ is a $n\times 1$ vector, $f_1\left(x\right)=x^TAx-x^Tx+a^Tx-b^Tx$, write $f_1\left(x\right)$ in the completed square form
$$\left(x-h\right)^TM\left(x-h\right)+g.$$
determine $M$,$h$,$g$.

I've noticed that a similar question answered in this link,
[Completing the square in matrix form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580902/completing-the-square-in-matrix-form). However, I dont think they answered that question. Because you'll always have an extra term $x^TMh$ that cannot be extinguished.

Comment: Are you sure that $x$ is not an $n \times 1$ vector?

Comment: The question doesn't mention this, so I assume it demands the general case that $x$ is $m\times n$.

Comment: $x$ is a vector and $g$ is a scalar.  Otherwise, this is way overcomplicated!

Comment: Assuming $x$ is a vector
$$\eqalign{
M &= \tfrac 12(A+A^T-2I) \\
h &= \tfrac 12M^{-1}(b-a) \\
g &= -h^TMh \\
}$$

Comment: Could you please tell more details? Did you assume that $A$ is a symmetric matrix?

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, then replace  $(A+A^T)\,$ by $(2A)\,$ in the formula for $M\;$